# Alerting input time returning incorrectly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to input a time and have it returned back to me so I can alert it. I get two errors: 1) "time.split is not a function"(which I guess is because I'm not passing a string 2) when I try to add .toString() to either the argument or to time.toString().split(/:/) it doesn't get returned correctly. How would I get it to alert the time? Thanks!

```
function changeTime(time) {
    time = time.split(/:/);

    if (time[0] < 12) {
        return (time[0] + time[1] + " AM"); 
    } else if (time[0] == 12) {
        return (time[0] + time[1] + " PM");
    } else if(time[0] > 12) {
        return ((time[0] - 12) + time[1] + " PM");
    } else {
        return("Please enter a valid time!");
    }
}

getTime.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("The time is " + changeTime(timeText));
});
```

EDIT: here are my input fields for "timeText" and "getTime"

```
   <button id="getTime">Get Time</button>
   <input type="time" id="timeText" />
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i think this is string `time.split(/:/)`

Comment: Then what is `time`? So that it would be easy to evaluate and answer.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy timeText is an time type input field, and "getTime" is a button. I will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `timeText` is an input field. In that case, to get the string, you have to call the value property.

I also wanted to make a couple improvements to your function

1. Your time was showing something like this `400PM`. I improved it so it now shows `4:00PM`.
2. I also made  a check to see if the time field had a value. Only if it did, would I alert the time. Previously it showed `The time is undefined pm`

```js
var getTime = document.getElementById("get-time");
var timeText = document.getElementById("time-text");

function changeTime(time) {
    time = time.split(/:/);

    if (time[0] < 12) {
        return (time[0] + ":" + time[1] + " AM"); 
    } else if (time[0] == 12) {
        return (time[0] + ":" + time[1] + " PM");
    } else if(time[0] > 12) {
        return ((time[0] - 12) + ":" + time[1] + " PM");
    } else {
        return("Please enter a valid time!");
    }
}

getTime.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (timeText.value) { 
      alert("The time is " + changeTime(timeText.value));
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="time-text" type="time">

<button id="get-time">Get Time</button>
```

Comment: This is definitely correct, but the only issue I'm having now is that 12:30 AM is getting returned as 00:30 AM